# Substract a value x from a Prometheus metric for a Grafana "single stat" with "Delta" activated?

Tags: testing, grafana, prometheus

Maybe the problem should be solved in another way.

I am using a Grafana SingleStat pane with "Delta" activated and the dashboard shows me "today so far".

Prometheus metric: `sum(request_duration_count{...})`

**Problem**:

- I have a metric counting requests. Between 03:00 and 06:00 an automated test triggers my service and the metric is incremented by value x. (I set a Grafana annotation at the starting point.)
- I want to get a single stat request count without the test requests.

**Advanced Problem**:

- Nagios checks every y minutes and also increments the counter.
- How can I remove these "test-counts"?

Any ideas?